# Access control id with OnItemDataBound property in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this nested datalist.

**EDIT**

```
<asp:DataList ID="mydatalist" DataKeyField="sid" ItemStyle-CssClass="lft_c_down"  runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="wholeC">
    <div class="ctop">
    <div class="lft_l">
    <div class="lft_l_top">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ipath")%>' Height="245px" Width="297px" />
    <br/>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="lft_r">

    <asp:Label ID="lbl_sid" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"sid") %>' runat="server" Visible="false" />
    <b class="products" >Product Name:</b>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl2" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ipath") %>' runat="server" />
    <br/>
    <b class="products">Brand:</b>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"brand") %>' runat="server" />
    <br/>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cdown">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_cmt" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="500px" placeholder="comment.."  />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server" Text="Comment" backcolor="black" BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Consolas" Font-Overline="False" 
    ForeColor="White" Height="34px" Width="108px" OnClick="cmt_Click" />


<asp:DataList ID = "dl_cmt" runat="server">
    <ItemStyle CssClass="coment" />
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblcmt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ecomment")%>' />
    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" style=" color:brown; font-family:Cursive; font-size:x-small; " runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("my_date","on {0}") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="lb_showMore" runat="server">Show More</asp:LinkButton>--%>
    </div>
    </div>

    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

It uses the property `onItemDataBound`.But with its use i am unable to access the id of this datalist.

```
public void cmtdatabound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        DataList dl = e.Item.FindControl("dl_cmt") as DataList;

        string str = gstr;
        sq.connection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 4 * from comment where sid='" + str + "' order by my_date desc", sq.con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        dl.DataSource = ds;
        dl.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Here the `dl` is null that means the id is not accessible.How do i access the id of the datalist here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sender parameter as `DataList` like this:

```
 DataList dl = sender as DataList;
```

Comment: How come the loop never ends of the function `cmtdatabound`

Comment: Because you are binding Datalist again on DataBound event. it goes into infinite loop. so you must bind datalist outside databound event

Comment: oh.. can i access this `dl` in another function say `myfun(){ dl.datsource=ds; }`

Comment: yes you can directly access this control with it's ID. myfun(){ dl_cmt.datsource=ds; }

Comment: Actually the `dl_cmt` is the id of datalist inside another datalist...if i could access it directly i wouldnt have to use `ondataitembound`

Comment: then you should show full code. you had only show one datalist code and you have write ondatabound event on dl_cmt. but you should bind this event with it's parent datalist

Comment: ok just add onItemDataBound event to mydatalist and your other code looks fine.